# AngularJs DatePicker is not respecting ng-model

Tags: angularjs

Actually, I am using [this combined date and time picker](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker), but it simply an extension of the standard , so I doubt that it is causing my problem.

Here's my HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker 
 ng-model="campaign.start_time" is-open="startDateTimePicker.isOpen"  />
```

I open the picker and select a date & time (which are, in any case, now by default), then I click a "Save" button which should send he data to the server.

However, when I breakpoint and look at `campaign`, several other fields which were bound to it, such as `campaign.title` (froma text input field) are set, but campaign.start_time is nulll.

Obviously, I am making a very simple mistake, but what?

---

The "Save" button looks like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" 
 ng-click="SaveCampaignEdit(campaign);" 
 accesskey='s' style="margin-left:10%">Save</button>
```

Comment: just provide a bit more code as with only one line it is a bit difficult to know where the error could be. Maybe a plnkr or jsbin sth...

Comment: I thought that Camoens would say  that (+1), but, honestly, I can't think what else to post. If you tell me what you want I will post it. I was just hoping that someone would point out a spelling error or something. After all, only the HTML  is mine.  The official demo Plunk at http://plnkr.co/edit/S8UqwvXNGmDcPXV7a0N3 works

Comment: How is your "save" button realized? A function which gets the object and makes an Ajax call? Or are you just using a plain "submit" button? e.g. are you using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit in your form ? The demo plunkr from your datepicker isn't showing that. So the overall <form> would be interesting and perhaps some snippets from your controller handling everything.